# Where IFS is defined

Tags: bash

I learned that

> The IFS environment variable deﬁ nes a list of characters the bash shell uses as ﬁeld separators. By default, the bash shell considers the following characters as ﬁeld separators
>   1. A space
>   2. A tab
>   3. newline

How could I find where `IFS` is defined.

```
$ type -a IFS 
-bash: type: IFS: not found
$ which IFS
which: no IFS in (/Users/me/anaconda3/bin:/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin)
```

Where could I find it?

Comment: The default value of `IFS` is *built into the shell itself*. It's not something external to the shell you can find without looking at the shell's source code.

Comment: ...specifically, see [`variables.c:517`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f/variables.c#L517)

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts (`type`, `which`) suggest that you are thinking of `IFS` as a *command*.  As noted in the text you quoted, it's a *shell variable*.

You can see what it is set to with:

```
declare -p IFS
```

You can change it like any other variable, like so:

```
IFS='|'
```

Reference: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS

Comment: I really can't recommend that cyberciti guide. `cat -etv <<<"$IFS"` doesn't distinguish between `unset IFS` and `IFS=''`, even though they behave quite differently -- whereas `declare -p` makes the distinction. [The bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#ifs) is perhaps a better-maintained reference.

Comment: (...strictly, it's possible to be an environment variable without being a shell variable, insofar as applications can use `setenv()` to create environment variables with names that aren't valid in a shell, but POSIX doesn't clearly define what a shell does in the presence of such names, and it's within-spec for a shell to simply ignore or even delete them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I'm thinking you could write a better answer than I have;  feel free to do so;  I hope mine (combined with your comments) is helpful to the OP, but I'll gladly defer to you if you want to post a whole answer